# Putting nested random effects in polr function

Tags: r, model, regression, mixed

I am trying to run an ordinal logistic regression mixed model with nested random effects using the polr function from package MASS.

average_Mg, average_Mn, and average_Zn are the predictor variables. the response variable is (Spawn_ID)

I have two random effects that are added into the model "(1|Time/ID)" (time is nested into ID and each ID has a different number of time because some ID's have more observations than other IDs) (see picture)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aQLA.png)

data:

```
data1 <- structure(list(Spawn_ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), average_Mg = c(0.0841567034686979, 
0.00262726492114602, 0.353259164624795, -0.0364882169624394, 
0.355390763410209, -0.151476304441742, -0.0936982567875358, 0.162382425722223, 
-1.42681140542971, -1.07244649331608, -0.781118702245109, -1.21952099438996, 
-1.38524008095868, -0.898983285649544, -1.01088138645042, -1.56153946055641, 
-1.21949786511762, -0.887755361220044, -1.28496187594515, -1.82368718501736, 
-1.44293956646485, -1.55766693069354, -1.58965315500885, -1.44731801677922, 
-1.90014469879122, -1.39433781118039, -1.3954911611769, -0.866262522744268, 
-0.893780676281797, -1.13725619637354, -1.50364564206296, -0.845596282408769, 
-0.911535321390588, -1.41202503488084, -1.16477711028459, -0.928588557438047, 
-1.0717825099406, -1.27071094552779, -0.102981887484371, -0.419552015986426, 
0.207549199784127, -0.26688619247063, -0.0285388879140084, -0.104483586190019, 
-0.374343912017509, -0.079286617457435, 0.502081027554914, 0.617397464912897, 
0.658216645632926, 0.426442596169416, 0.437015933595451, -1.09407187513834, 
-0.289722984650423, 0.189585827711078, 0.388488397202216, -0.814972632964376, 
0.0191088328270176, -0.0788536189757766, -1.01469763732677, -0.532896761096259, 
-0.319455285766885, 0.32814415425849, -1.10320849618017, -0.802227061565149, 
-0.540984260212337, -1.14703007008055, -0.482835715257794, -1.23114539323637, 
-0.881874890913403, -0.479104993907372, 0.722375571708869, 0.890893182481924, 
1.1899980340988, 0.784338248057351, 0.6979419698913, 1.10833467622332, 
0.749554401158789, 0.761841531876783, 1.38243732271989, 1.38537086804658, 
0.686397638698291, 1.38660240844063, 1.90358175564482, 1.30513882860368, 
0.9706833889022, 2.02786238069347, 0.633278771850179, 0.773554195390702, 
1.26407209402018, 0.711780226990467, 1.12404623953355, 0.772411304871684, 
0.746907192859431, 1.26546029276059, 0.754582077531832, 0.97865102792368, 
1.25739249978455, 1.00030371910859, 1.20251423376581, 0.508886239812359, 
1.0614400765502, 1.15560112394629, 0.810899892639843, 0.864356170995008, 
1.0722853284304, 0.459017471399662, 0.622305015414975, 0.654778017554924, 
0.630012469467092, 1.66357555743707, 1.51486425579301, 0.468256912570358, 
1.46986769298999, 0.842853031161864, 0.527443923164085, 0.878231897515369, 
1.01564664723517, 0.548373164352724, -1.54705977070176, -1.7628880927376, 
-1.93886600741023, -1.75280825324115, -1.06329603003556, -1.76583856532739, 
-2.03620478132805, -1.37852741943318, 0.491445103158986, 0.579237889782203, 
0.581147814257234, 0.587993370694159, 0.673660535135936, 0.773224639425602, 
0.472056000685565, 0.803037596940575, 0.686349802316703, 0.67297390357697, 
0.877084884098423, 0.116853127650954, 0.633207695175741, 0.475407810726902, 
0.410454398351338, 0.761825383439366, 0.049981065597767, 0.352528868363907, 
1.08494544768163), average_Mn = c(0.550041395336084, 0.106013801445048, 
0.195501740474326, 0.443055327801251, 0.166039412117922, 0.306826485641131, 
0.0779488541952551, 0.253041943200378, -0.398175664467298, -0.248653116953824, 
1.62701418452763, 2.12294900204613, -0.653505561079324, 1.18649551151282, 
1.73706605332464, -0.663237964024895, -0.502022515338005, 1.37488148179862, 
1.52730443891077, -1.02791508823558, -0.912000741847277, -1.13836183212639, 
-1.0203769070181, -0.944729930532721, -1.08022080193656, -0.798637523498975, 
-0.892966674264699, -0.106867747759299, -0.446077807686831, 0.260985129778798, 
0.34207999245625, -0.256052324398952, -0.455901687059591, -0.124589605852459, 
-0.330899017708168, -0.155941754430574, 0.179724557145222, -0.13333037309261, 
-0.467033378092841, -1.02354293597083, -0.324678510862249, -0.780338971498965, 
-0.638323663037884, -0.833876759864611, -1.23290374823043, -0.791651926017789, 
-0.507461130613381, -0.8368428812325, -0.0557361418099642, -0.804531913988396, 
-0.704346938462444, -0.483778753666885, 0.393712753506288, 0.427715184816051, 
0.479775271348421, -0.28130811769396, 0.485295306906789, 0.29873238753337, 
-0.32311305698219, -0.153688760742991, 0.566586154995381, 0.432231338528875, 
1.06596225482086, 1.35634853919191, 3.80694326707882, 0.810475117293976, 
3.0387608847462, 0.633718464176746, 1.1751890651466, 3.9845446592986, 
-1.37297875557724, -1.09420268685371, -0.962614525736854, -1.29805138281804, 
-1.31055976157738, -0.925719147858883, -1.23243978183704, -1.33945462492742, 
-0.733417598434015, -0.930363022530595, -1.27774840900127, -0.551645520494324, 
1.07748304807901, -0.396816101914801, -0.619403529151145, 0.904015824338447, 
-0.287220128038401, -0.413048098445259, 0.612345039773056, 0.12520419272066, 
0.144889119165393, -0.376872327860885, -0.371321461123647, 0.713414294431202, 
-0.220319649249486, 1.91457944140036, 1.96765430981412, -0.121347747943895, 
1.83594114293694, -0.874846076775421, 1.57970089137696, 1.93625153606136, 
0.346364402583701, 1.77363591575721, 0.715776292044604, -0.11504600156397, 
0.957194866002839, -0.887101387136546, -0.780049232064872, -0.336706490132965, 
-0.70438883179631, -0.873817482659086, -0.284434200328209, -0.568305044660584, 
-0.775993306095371, -0.771770658609636, -0.383838373137703, -0.811970593682299, 
-0.73465457432939, 0.0911351344017551, 1.2707682140586, -0.777318831552788, 
1.11134230637355, -0.783796841885501, 0.259370669933754, 1.73241147006831, 
-0.725970777900951, -0.438118569726494, -0.278337133147783, -0.493758812846972, 
-0.518179622331699, -0.389789488287258, -0.298381997017347, -0.612423478602631, 
-0.429659970678406, -0.292999247051666, -0.435183828919258, -0.897633859213429, 
0.507974413224703, 1.43201049921323, -0.66047577071763, 0.786340467145023, 
-0.95656045144662, -0.132752976801546, 1.18466694854915), average_Zn = c(0.199618761426643, 
0.591792310386536, 1.3751346661716, 0.332582639073901, 0.560402369414685, 
0.11570820588524, 0.192150397195304, 1.39288706671957, -0.394083581015067, 
-0.0798076017654593, 1.17669193020793, 0.607211261125105, -0.452359206037806, 
0.771410079352111, 0.494544784665782, -0.625267178823271, -0.39226745167263, 
1.16595745311139, 0.395578830413474, -1.34293822466577, -0.742961944779728, 
-1.55476909975203, -1.21117698813619, -0.705958753206111, -1.37118754349972, 
-0.917928244368175, -0.974434964905969, -1.01929394953207, -1.12532371386981, 
-1.22700631035692, -1.46133511017614, -0.952449170432, -1.21027641358059, 
-1.3226625940125, -1.16430485224588, -1.08770522025381, -1.18121144700268, 
-1.40033431712296, -0.618587673725525, -0.91706750820117, 0.41088121270189, 
-0.78430313474907, -0.409059258341318, -0.975516971079657, -1.27140585793008, 
-0.198796133331597, -0.429336908924874, -0.0174222425394045, 
-0.161004481467468, -0.405810552877399, -0.370285632509627, -0.89866639987887, 
1.10645284167993, 1.8809570525936, 1.92254222169752, -0.0950224222539316, 
1.58853988090432, 1.78386607934181, -0.817728723571643, 0.459412598781715, 
1.423493404365, 1.7768774695448, -1.12006569075839, -0.751966514798299, 
-0.488043380249217, -1.11596293893295, 0.273653921626916, -1.30713710349688, 
-0.886375551803829, 0.0239199838971528, -1.3593629685693, -0.643843217883837, 
-0.281272478019681, -1.30622537314287, -1.33112371265123, -0.909101703993645, 
-1.12755493783614, -1.40003719660867, -0.290337728601771, -0.28987232858238, 
-1.19056584307422, -0.193624949117038, 0.975332436429838, -0.218160046225909, 
-0.132462974128803, 1.39468641578899, -0.302150834825655, -0.107400685186729, 
1.125970810338, -0.256092735038377, 0.158506693687128, -0.378339394736207, 
-0.349357413758689, 0.803679188551612, -0.146048595417096, -0.286845588476566, 
0.158259418849209, -0.323113138916157, 0.108646496285904, -0.771878347558138, 
0.0273033684358348, 0.0453235133932348, 1.28361673646552, 1.29073622845612, 
1.24630790251793, 0.944986804400661, 0.981991016697687, 1.3473053430083, 
0.827378725150942, 2.48208427225106, 2.69830294706435, 1.03039606923181, 
2.27492560926846, 1.10744827135352, 1.35324680735362, 1.84388638700427, 
1.52873550347441, 1.40071898822651, 0.260928795100606, -1.16734754082697, 
-0.878145608518404, -0.00331768573206932, -0.910939824808822, 
0.125144947309071, -1.67327192782442, -0.531813491778335, -0.546522958404239, 
-0.0196439100156154, 0.0745476695275746, 0.794370508556172, -0.210218336601184, 
0.445705743628815, 0.0718198426307307, -0.122444182892431, 0.184211311538213, 
0.183194361394073, 1.12410771197491, -0.741883323524288, 0.716760255429898, 
1.76025647136123, -0.00419702451761512, 1.25254232235371, -0.880576082155036, 
-0.00114985682377106, 1.78721959263295), ID = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L), .Label = c("BLA14", 
"BLA2", "BLA20", "BLA209", "BLA21", "BLA211", "BLA238", "BLA24", 
"BLA25", "BLA283", "BLA307", "BLA31", "BLA42", "BLA47", "BLA5", 
"BLA79", "BLA80"), class = "factor"), Time = structure(c(2L, 
5L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 
4L, 7L, 10L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 
3L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 
2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 
10L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 
9L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 
1L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 
6L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 
2L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 7L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"), class = c("ordered", "factor"
))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -145L))
```

Current code for model

```
model2<- polr(Spawn_ID ~ average_Mg + average_Mn + average_Zn + (1| ID/Time), data = data1,  method = "logistic", Hess = TRUE)
```

error message

```
Error in family$linkfun(mustart) : 
  Argument mu must be a nonempty numeric vector
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In eval(predvars, data, env) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.ordered") for "/"
2: In Ops.factor(1, ID/Time) : ‘|’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: I don’t think `polr` is designed for mixed effects.

Comment: the mixed package doesnt exist anymore, the clmm function from ordinal doesn't compute predictors, the clmm2 doesn't allow random effects, and I am having a hard time fitting my brm model.

Comment: Dear confused individual: Your confusion might be resolved with statistical background: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238581/how-to-use-ordinal-logistic-regression-with-random-effects

Comment: If you are preparing another question with code and data, then it should be redone in my opinion. The answer to this one appears to be     Not possible.